# Cannot find href element by xpath using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to locate a link on a page and click on it.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open(&quot;datareport1?code=999&quot;, &quot;myWin&quot;, &quot;scrollbars=yes,width=1200,height=500&quot;); return false;">ClickLink</a>
```

I'm trying to find element by the copied relative xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="finsummary"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')
```

However this fails.
Alternatively the link is inside parent tag:

```
<td style="font-size: 10px;font-weight: normal;font-family: verdana " class="sorting_1"></td>
```

I'm trying to find this element by classname :

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'sorting_1')
```

This fails too.
It should be noted that this page has javascript enabled that causes it to auto refresh after a few seconds, I'm unsure if this causes problems.

Comment: Is it certain that the element has already been loaded at the time of access and is not an element that is living in an iframe? Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: I had no understanding of having to switch between frames until I read your comment. Thanks a lot, the element was indeed inside an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment - If you need to work with [frames or iframes, WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/) allows you to interact with elements present in one by switching to the iframe:

```
...
# find iframe by favorite selector (tag, id, name, ...)
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")
# switch into iframe
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
# find your element
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="finsummary"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a')
```